# QApplication::processEvents() "building up" events?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am working on an application that needs to carry out a computation that can be interrupted, but only when the app is in focus. To that end, I do this:

```
while (important thing is true) {
    QApplication::processEvents();
    
    bool focus = amIinFocus();

    if (focus) {
        mInterrupted = true;
        return success;
    }
}
```

Now, this (mostly) works. When the app is not in focus, and I have another app in focus (like Word), and hit `ESC` my app doesn't stop. However, the minute I minimize Word, my app stops the work. I'm guessing because we're not actually "ignoring" the `ESC` presses in the queue. Is there some way of "removing" them? Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: Blocking while-loops are always questionable at best in Qt.  Can you move your computation to a separate thread, instead?  You could set an atomic variable if you want to interrupt the computation, then call `join()` on the thread to wait for it to see that the atomic variable has been set, and exit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't my application, so the code I'm editing can't be spun into a separate thread. Maybe I should just forgo the processEvents(...) call...

Comment: The other option would be to have a slot-method (MyMethod()) that does just a short amount of computation, then calls QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(MyMethod()) so that it will be called again in the next iteration of the Qt event loop.  That way the event loop is never blocked for long.  Downside is you have to save your computation’s ongoing state in member-variables so that you can resume your computations across calls.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the code shown is supposed to do.  At first glance it continuously processes events until the application gets the input focus at which point it sets `mInterrupted ` and returns.  That being the case it shouldn't come as any surprise that when some other app such as Word is minimized your app gets the input focus an stops/quits.  I suspect what you really want is an application wide event filter.  Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: I should explain better. I hit ESC repeatedly in Word which doesn’t affect anything. Then, I minimize word, my app quits (my app probably regains focus when Word gets minimized).

Comment: Keypresses will never enter your queue if another application has focus.  That's the definition of focus -- the queue to which keyboard events are delivered.

Comment: Calling `processEvents()` is a hack and if you ever need it there's probably something wrong with your design. Why is the program not returning to the event loop regularly so events get handled the normal way?